# AMQ load balancing cluster setup

Tags: activemq-classic, cluster-computing, load-balancing

i know that there is a lot if information about AMQ cluster but i dont know how to setup this.. 
I need a load balancing cluster, with two machines, and two instances in each machine like 192.168.0.1 (instance1,instance2) 192.168.0.2(instance3,instance4). 
My openwire ports are 0.0.0.0:61617 - 0.0.0.0:61620.
Was found some solutions over the internet like:

Instance1

```
<networkConnectors>
 <networkConnector name="instance1-instance3-instance4" uri="masterslave:(tcp://192.168.0.2:61619,tcp://192.168.0.2:61620)" />
</networkConnectors>
<persistenceAdapter>
 <kahaDB directory="${activemq.data}/kahadb1" />
</persistenceAdapter>
```

instance2:

```
<networkConnectors>
 <networkConnector name="instance2-instance3-instance4" uri="masterslave:(tcp://192.168.0.2:61619,tcp://192.168.0.2:61620)" />
</networkConnectors>
<persistenceAdapter>
 <kahaDB directory="${activemq.data}/kahadb1" />
</persistenceAdapter>
```

instance3:

```
<networkConnectors>
 <networkConnector name="instance3-instance1-instance2" uri="masterslave:(tcp://192.168.0.1:61617,tcp://192.168.0.1:61618)" />
</networkConnectors>
<persistenceAdapter>
 <kahaDB directory="${activemq.data}/kahadb2" />
</persistenceAdapter>
```

instance4:

```
<networkConnectors>
 <networkConnector name="instance4-instance1-instance2" uri="masterslave:(tcp://192.168.0.1:61617,tcp://192.168.0.1:61618)" />
 <networkConnector name="FAILOVER" 
        uri="static:(failover:(tcp://192.168.0.1:61617,tcp://192.168.0.2:61619,tcp://192.168.0.1:61618,tcp://192.168.0.2:61620))?randomize=false" 
        dynamicOnly="true" 
        networkTTL="4" 
        duplex="true"/>
</networkConnectors>
<persistenceAdapter>
 <kahaDB directory="${activemq.data}/kahadb2" />
</persistenceAdapter>
```

And it works, connecting to each other, when one node falls down, instance4 reconnect to another with this failover string. But i dont know is it works fine or it doesnt work, tell me pls?? 
Maybe somebody made LB cluster and can give xml files?Please. And sorry if my english not so good. I am from other country)

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you are asking about

Comment: I cant understand how works that network of brokers in my first message. Does it balance messages or not, and how can i test it :) sorry for my english

Comment: It all depends on the consumers. If broker1 and broker2 is connected in a network of brokers - messages will flow from broker1 to broker2 if broker2 has a connected consumer and broker1 has messages (on a specific destination). Load balancing between multiple consumers on a specific queue will happend in a network of brokers, as will it on a single broker with multiple consumers.

Comment: Why when i'm connecting client, only first broker get message?
consumer -Durl=failover:(tcp://192.168.0.1:61617,tcp://192.168.0.2:61619,tcp://192.168.0.1:61618,tcp://192.168.0.2:61620)?randomize=false
number of consumers is 1 on both brokers.
If consumer -Durl=failover:(tcp://192.168.0.2:61619,tcp://192.168.0.1:61618,tcp://192.168.0.2:61620)?randomize=false  (without first adress, then load balance works fine).

Answer (score 0):

The solution to scale out (load balance from a broker perspective) an ActiveMQ deployment is called Network of Brokers. The network consists of multiple logical nodes, which you seem to be setting up. These nodes can be of master-slave type, to cover for machine failure etc.

There are example configs inside the ActiveMQ distribution that you can look at.

Comment: Can someone please post the documentation link to setup network of brokers to distribute the load?